# comparing a table and a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form, a table ("my_table") and a query ("my_query").

I want a function to look if any of the table's record's IDs ("my_ID") match with the IDs of the query (also "my_ID") to update a field ("my_Property") of given record with a value from the form.

I copied and modified [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Data-Access-Objects/modify-an-existing-record-in-a-dao-recordset). My code causes an error (have to translate): *"Runtime error '3061': 1 parameter was expected, but too few parameters were passed."*

I think the issue is that in the if loop I don't compare tbl.Fields("my_ID") with a discreet value but with a set values. Maybe I should also iterate through all values of qry.Fields("my_ID") but I don't see how to do the code. Also, this would significantly slow down the already slow process since my_Table contains more than 40,000 records. Is there a faster method of comparing the ids?

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Dim tbl As Recordset
    Set tbl = db.OpenRecordset("my_Table")

    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Set qry = db.OpenRecordset("my_Query")

    tbl.MoveFirst
    Do Until tbl.EOF
            If tbl.Fields("my_ID") = qry.Fields("my_ID") Then
                tbl.Edit
                tbl.Fields("my_Property") = Me!textbox1.Value
                tbl.Update
            End If
        tbl.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: create a new query to join the table and the query on ID's, then loop through this recordset

Comment: Actually you don't need VBA for this at all. Create the JOIN query as @HarassedDad wrote, and change it into an UPDATE query to directly update the column.

Answer (score 0):

As @Harassed Dad and @Andre suggested I simply copied "my_query" and changed the copy to an update query "my_updatequery" with the update field of "my_Property" set to
[Forms]![My_Form]![tbx_my_Value]. Then I changed the code for the button to:

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "my_updatequery"
        Forms.my_Form.Subform2.Requery
End Sub
```

Forms.my_Form.Subform2.Requery updates basically a subform showing the "my_query"-query.

I will look further for another way to call the update query to avoid the two prompts that opening an update query always entails.

edit:

To to avoid the propmts I simply turned Warnings off and on again:

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "my_updatequery"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Forms.my_Form.Subform2.Requery
End Sub
```

Not the most elegant way but it will do the job.